# Why are there two indefinite articles in "the Babymetal craze is a perverse a pop confection but resistance is futile"?

Tags: indefinite-article

The following is the subtitle of the article [*Babymetal: Japan's rockers in knee socks*](http://www.theguardian.com/music/musicblog/2014/mar/13/babymetal-craze-japan-rockers-knee-socks)  from The Guardian. In it, I don't understand why indefinite articles appeared before and after the adjective "perverse".

> Fronted by three dancing Japanese teens and sounding somewhere inbetween Skrillex and Aqua: the Babymetal craze is **a** perverse **a** pop confection but resistance is futile

By the way, it's futile indeed.

Comment: Meta discussion on closing typo questions: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2716/230

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a typo. One article too many.

> Fronted by three dancing Japanese teens and sounding somewhere in between Skrillex and Aqua: the Babymetal craze is **a perverse pop confection** but resistance is futile

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo.  Should probably be

> ... the Babymetal crase is ***so*** perverse a pop confection...

Perhaps the author first typed "***a*** perverse pop confection" but then thought to put a twist on it, yet failed to change the '**a**' to a '**so**'.

Similar expressions (with the indefinite article between an adjective and a noun):

> Where did you find **such an idea**?
>   They built as **neat a house** as I'd never seen.

Comment: Do you really say "as I'd *never* seen" there -- i.e. "never" not "ever"?    In my dialect we say "That's as big a pumpkin as I've *ever* seen".

Comment: There is a sentence in the middle of the article "Babymetal are **as** demented and perverse a pop confection as anything in living memory, and yet the whole thing is delivered with such vitality and verve that resistance is effectively futile." So, it might be "as". But, it is a part of "as ... as anything" construction.